# How to update Dialog Height on validation errors?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using the Dialog Framework in Primefaces 4.0 and I have the height set to the default (auto) which is fine until I click the `Add` button and it displays a validation message. Now the dialog height is too small and doesn't auto resize.

How can I make the dialog resize it's height on validation errors?

Before Validation Errors:

[image: Before validation errors]

After Validation Errors:

[image: With Validation Errors]

add.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Add Group</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="addGroupForm">
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="10" width="300">  
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Group Name" />  
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{userGroupBacking.newGroup}" required="true" requiredMessage="Group Name is Required" />  

            <h:panelGroup></h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:commandButton value="Add" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" actionListener="#{userGroupBacking.addGroup}" update="@form" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" actionListener="#{userGroupBacking.cancelAddGroup}" immediate="true" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid> 
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your dialog doesn't have fixed height, second make sure that overflow of the DOM element where the notification resides in the dialog has overflow properly set. Some dialogs are a bit tricky and do not re-size easily without closing and opening again, it would be easier to help you if you could show the actual dialog. My first tip would be to catch an event in front end with jQuery and resize the dialog accordingly.

Comment: I'm using the primefaces Dialog Framework. The code i posted IS the actual dialog.

Comment: so i guess you include this part in a <p:dialog>?

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkBasic.jsf it's new to primefaces 4.0. Different than a normal dialog on the page.

Comment: ok, im still in 3.5, i'll try to implement this at my test project and try to come up with a solution. But it kind of looks like a bug in front-end.